# Swap Mouse Button using AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I use mouse with left-hand. My system is shared with other people who are right handed. So, I need frequently to switch mouse button.

I would like to know how to swap mouse button using AppleScript? I am using default mouse come with my iMac machine.

Answer (score 3):

I only tested this with the normal version of the preference pane, and it doesn't probably work if you have a Magic Mouse:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal pane "com.apple.preference.mouse"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    tell radio group 1 of window 1
        if value of radio button 1 is 1 then
            click radio button 2
        else
            click radio button 1
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

The setting is stored in this key, but I don't know any way to apply changes to it immediately:

```
defaults -currentHost read -g com.apple.mouse.swapLeftRightButton
```

You could also use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<item>
<name>test</name>
<identifier>test</identifier>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F1, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::VK_CONFIG_TOGGLE_swapbuttons</autogen>
</item>
<item>
<name>swapbuttons</name>
<identifier vk_config="true">swapbuttons</identifier>
<autogen>__PointingButtonToPointingButton__ PointingButton::LEFT, PointingButton::RIGHT</autogen>
<autogen>__PointingButtonToPointingButton__ PointingButton::RIGHT, PointingButton::LEFT</autogen>
</item>
</root>
```

See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got the error error "System Events got an error: Access for assistive devices is disabled." number -1719 from window 1 of process "System Preferences"

Comment: You just have to enable access for assistive devices in the accessibility preference pane.

Comment: Now I am getting "System Events got an error: Can’t get radio group 1 of window 1 of process \"System Preferences\". Invalid index." number -1719 from radio group 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences"

Comment: It has drop down under Secondary Click in Point & Click tag.

Comment: As mentioned in your answer, my mouse is Magic mouse and it is not working for it.

Comment: I don't have a Magic Mouse to test with, but you could try something like [this script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680778/how-to-use-applescript-to-toggle-the-language-setting-of-new-dictation-tool-10/11720145#11720145).

Comment: Is there a way to do this without opening up System Preferences in the background?

Answer (score 2):

I implemented it in JavaScript and tested it on macOS Ventura (13.0) with Magic Mouse.

```js
#!/usr/bin/env osascript -l JavaScript
// Launch System Settings
Application("System Settings").reveal();
const settings = Application("System Events").applicationProcesses.byName("System Settings")

// Select Mouse panel
settings.frontmost = true

delay(1)

const mouse_btn = settings.menuBars[0].menuBarItems["View"].menus["View"].menuItems["mouse"]
mouse_btn.click();

delay(1)

// Switch Secondary Click
const popup_btn = settings.windows[0].groups[0].splitterGroups[0].groups[1].groups[0].scrollAreas[0].groups[0].popUpButtons.byName("Secondary click")

popup_btn.click()
if (popup_btn.value() == "Click Right Side") {
    popup_btn.menus.menuItems["Click Left Side"].click()
}
else {
    popup_btn.menus.menuItems["Click Right Side"].click()
}

// Close System Settings
Application("System Settings").quit()
```

[source code](https://gist.github.com/zeewinpeng/a4e4efbe4ac090bac234b9c03adae7a2)

Comment: This worked so well!

Comment: One needs to create this as a Quick Action, with some unique name, e.g. swap_mouse_buttons, and then later in Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services to find the same name in General section (you might need to kill Settings and restart them) and assign a global keyboard shortcut to it

Comment: In addition you might need to execute `Application("System Settings").quit()` at the beginning of this script because the script is only the happy path in case System Settings are not already open (which is going to be the majority of the cases I guess). Anyway long story short is that the script as it is in the answer will not work as expected if System Settings are already open

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem, but I just tested that the script still runs well when the System Settings are already openned.

However, I found another problem, that is, when the system settings are closed, there is a probability that the switch to the mouse panel will fail. I added a `delay(1)` after focused on the System Settings to solve this problem. 

You can try to see if that solves the problem you mentioned.

Comment: Automator > Quick Action > Javascript Script > paste the code there > Cmd + S to save it

Answer (score -1):

I've updated this code to work with my version of macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (can't guarantee it will work with other versions):

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal pane "com.apple.preference.mouse"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    tell radio group "Primary mouse button:" of window "Mouse"
        if value of radio button "Left" is 1 then
            click radio button "Right"
        else
            click radio button "Left"
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: The AppleScript code in Lri's answer does not need any updating to work with macOS Mojave with an ordinary mouse and works exactly as is. All you've done is use the name of the UI element vs. is number and doesn't change the mechanics of what's happening.

Comment: Well, what was provided did not work for me but the code above did. Just wanted to share in case anyone else had a similar issue.