# Can I create a keyboard shortcut to toggle the primary mouse button between left and right?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, shortcut

I switch between my left and right hand for my mouse a lot, and every time I do, I have to go to System Preferences > Mouse > and switch the Primary mouse button. Is there any way I can create a keyboard shortcut to toggle this setting? I'm willing to figure out AppleScript if that would help me

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has already been answered here:

[Swap Mouse Button using AppleScript](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89721/swap-mouse-button-using-applescript)

Tested it and the code works for a normal external mouse.